# Finite momentum excitonic wave function

Tags: condensed-matter, semiconductor-physics

In a system in which we want to obtain the excitonic ground state. One may use the 1s excitonic wave function which appears in momentum-space as:

$$ \phi(\vec{k})_{1s}=\frac{\sqrt{8 \pi} \beta^2}{(\beta^2+|\vec{k}|^2 )^{3/2}}$$

which for a zero-exciton momentum state appears in the eigenvalue equation as follows:

$$ E_{ex} \phi(\vec{k}) = [E_c(\vec{k}) - E_v(\vec{k})] \phi(\vec{k})+\frac{1}{A} \sum_{\vec{q}}\phi(\vec{k}-\vec{q})V(\vec{q})$$

Now if we we wanted to look at a non-zero excitonic state with momentum $\vec{Q}$ in which the kinetic energy part of the above equation can appear as $E_c(\vec{k}+\vec{Q}) - E_v(\vec{k})$

Does this require a change in excitonic wave function to describe this eigenvalue state or is the previously used wave function still sufficient in obtaining the excitonic energies at non-zero momentum.

EDIT:
Would this be that if we call the new wave function $\Psi(\vec{k_e},\vec{k_h})$ then it would follow that
$$\Psi(\vec{k_e},\vec{k_h})=\delta_{k_e-k_h,Q}\phi(\vec{k})_{1s}$$
Hence, as $\vec{k_e}-\vec{k_h}=\vec{Q}$:
$$\Psi(\vec{k_e},\vec{k_h})=\phi(\vec{k})_{1s}$$